# Drivers for Marvell 88SE9230 SATA controller on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, raid, sata

I have just purchased a SuperMicro X10SBA, where i intend to use the onboard Marvell 88SE923 SATA controller for RAID1. Unfortunately SuperMicro has written that RAID is only compatible on Windows platform.

How do i determine that it is possible to run in linux, and how do you choose the right distribution that could make it less painful to get up running?

Comment: I'd like to buy the same board. Does RAID1 work with Debian 8 today? Thanks

Comment: I got RAID running, its some time ago so i do not know the exact procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, the Marvel; 88se9230 is supported in newer kernels (since 2013 and kernel 3.2 at least). See [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54561)  bug report and [these](http://marc.info/?l=linux-ide&w=2&r=1&s=88SE9230&q=b) messages to the linux-ide mailing list.

Based on the above, it should be supported by most recent distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a patch for this.  See this site:
[Marvel Patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42679)

Comment: That looks like good news to me, but will it mean i have to do anything special on my clean install of Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: You'd have to diff the kernel to verify whether the patch exists.

Comment: So there is stil a risk that the implementation is missing even though that i use the latest version Linux Kernel?

Comment: Right.  Or, you can just try one version higher than the one mentioned in the patch and see whether the device is recognized.